# how to change the value of random numbers using conditional statement

Tags: flash, actionscript, adobe, conditional-statements

I am doing a random number generator with 5 dynamic text. what I want to do is that when showRandom_txt = 1 then the other texts should be equal to zero

```
//1.
function randomNumbers(min:Number,max:Number) {
   var Results:Number=Math.floor(Math.random()*max)+min;
   return Results;
}

function randomNumber(){
   var Results:Number=Math.floor(Math.random()*(1+1-0))+0;
   return Results;
}


//2.
generate_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, showRandomnumber);

//3.
function showRandomnumber(event:MouseEvent):void{
   showRandom_txt.text = randomNumber();
   showRandom2_txt.text = randomNumbers(0,9);
   showRandom3_txt.text = randomNumbers(0,9);
   showRandom4_txt.text = randomNumbers(0,9);
   showRandom5_txt.text = randomNumbers(0,9);
}
```

i am new to AS3 and i would really apreciate your help. thanks

Comment: Do you know what a conditional statement is?

Comment: No need to `-0` or `+0` in your `randomNumber()` function.

Comment: @Xymostech yes i do. if, else, switch. but i am not very familiar with it yet since i am a newbie. i was trying to make a conditional statement where if showRandom_txt is equal to 1 then the other numbers should be equal to zero

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To evaluate equality use the [`==`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/operators.html) [operator](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/operators.html).

This could be tested from the text field, as in:

```
if(showRandom_txt.text == "1") {}
```

Perhaps better would be test against numeric type, as in:

```
var n:Number = randomNumber();
if(n == 1) {}
```

Using an if / else implementation:

```
function showRandomNumber(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    var n:Number = randomNumber();
    showRandom_txt.text = n.toString();

    if (n == 1)
    {
        showRandom2_txt.text = showRandom3_txt.text = showRandom4_txt.text = showRandom5_txt.text = "0";
    }
    else
    {
        showRandom2_txt.text = randomNumbers(0, 9).toString();
        showRandom3_txt.text = randomNumbers(0, 9).toString();
        showRandom4_txt.text = randomNumbers(0, 9).toString();
        showRandom5_txt.text = randomNumbers(0, 9).toString();
    }
}
```

Using a switch block:

```
function showRandomNumber(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    var n:Number = randomNumber();
    showRandom_txt.text = n.toString();

    switch(n)
    {
        case 1:
            showRandom2_txt.text = showRandom3_txt.text = showRandom4_txt.text = showRandom5_txt.text = "0";
            break;
        default:
            showRandom2_txt.text = randomNumbers(0, 9).toString();
            showRandom3_txt.text = randomNumbers(0, 9).toString();
            showRandom4_txt.text = randomNumbers(0, 9).toString();
            showRandom5_txt.text = randomNumbers(0, 9).toString();
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: wow! thanks for your help. i tried it and it's working now. :)